# Cannot import blueprints with my Flask application

Tags: python, flask

My Project structure is as follows:
[image]

in the `app/__init__.py` file I have tried to register the blue prints

```
from flask import Flask
from app.blueprints.data_endpoints.routes import data_endpoints
from app.blueprints.user_endpoints.routes import user_endpoints


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.register_blueprint(data_endpoints)
    app.register_blueprint(user_endpoints)

    return app
```

But I get the error:

```
from app.blueprints.data_endpoints.routes import data_endpoints
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.blueprints'
```

I also tried running it with

```
from .blueprints.data_endpoints.routes import data_endpoints
from .blueprints.user_endpoints.routes import user_endpoints
```

But I still get the error:

```
from .blueprints.data_endpoints.routes import data_endpoints
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: How do you run your app?